# Coordinated input in all text boxes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an exercise and I do not understand how to do it.

Build a control with 5 text boxes that the input in all text boxes is correlated. Changing input in one box changes the input in the rest of the box.

```
class App extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MultiInput />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function SameInput(props) {
  return <input type="text" name="sameInput"/>
}

class MultiInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "ho" };
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <SameInput value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}></SameInput><br />
      <SameInput value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}></SameInput><br />
      <SameInput value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}></SameInput><br />
    </div>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You need to be more clear about what your question is. What is the code doing when you run it, what have you done to try and debug the problem.

Comment: What is the error? Please describe about the issue in detail

Comment: There are no bugs or errors, I just cant get the job done.
I dont understand how to do it and asking for some help.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing onChange event handler function and value to SameInput functional component but you are not actually handling them in input text field in SameInput function of input element.

Try with below change it would work

```
 function SameInput(props) {
     return <input type="text" name="sameInput" onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value}/>
  }
```

Comment: @saliweizman Please do upvote and accept the answer if my solution helped resolving the issue so that it will help future readers to try out this solution for the same problem